# Asp.net Random for id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net with c# in backcode. 
I want to random data for `OrderID` (table `Orders`) when I insert data into sql.
how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: um...you want a random value for an identity field?

Comment: that's generally considered bad practice. If you're looking for something unique across multiple databases try a guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what the range was. If you want numbers between 1 and 1,000,000 inclusive then you could do something like this:

```
var rand = new Random();
var myRandomNumber = rand.Next(1, 1000000);
```

Comment: This is very dangerous as there are no guarantees of non-repeating numbers.

Comment: He didn't ask for an ID, that's what everyone is assuming. I (perhaps naively) did not make that assumption :)

He asked for random data, and that's what I gave him...

Comment: I think just going by the fieldname 'OrderID', uniqueness is a reasonable requirement to assume.

Comment: `OrderID` is a data for a ID. I think it's clear, sorry. Thanks for help.

Comment: The range from 1 to 1000 is Ok, My data is small.

Answer (score 1):

In your Table design Select OrderID field and select Identity Specification  and set is Identity to yes.

Comment: This is definitely the correct approach, but is of course strictly wrong in direct answer to the question (because the identity is not random, obviously), maybe worth noting :) (I upvoted you, of course).

Comment: Hi. I want do it in aspx.cs file, not modify in sql server

Answer (score 0):

1. if OrderId is INT and primary key then it should be an identity column. while inserting a new record you do not need to pass any OrderId as it is identity.
2. if for some reason (won't recommended) you want to generate it in code behind. Get the last inserted OrderId and increment it. (need to be careful about concurrency issues)

If you have hold on your DB. you should go for first approach.

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your database table of type [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) and set the default value to [NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx). This column will automatically be assigned a random and unique [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) for you to use in your applications.

If you want something "more numeric" I can recommend this article, [An alternative to GUIDs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Guids/75506/) on [www.sqlservercentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com), which I found really interesting.